# Install a 2nd copy of VS2008 in same server?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, bids

We currently have a version of VS2008 Professional installed in our server that's been there for ages. Someone, many years ago, installed it. This server has Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1617.0, and MS Visual Studio 2008 9.0.30729.4462 QFE.

Anyways, in the server, I managed to set up and ReportServer, I can build/publish SSRS reports, and also create SSAS cubes. So everything's running more or less fine.

The problem is that, lately, while working on a cube in VS2008, when I click on tab "Calculations", the VS IDE crashes and closes. So I was thinking of uninstalling and re-installing. The problem is that I don't know how that affects our current setup, and most importantly, I'm not sure how that affects the BIDS part of Visual Studio.

Since I've always had my doubts as to what's needed to run SSAS and SSRS, instead of messing with that, I was hoping I could just install a fresh version. If this fresh install works, then I can uninstall the old version. I'm not even certain if the version I have of VS2008 is the same one installed.

I tried to repair the installation, but that didn't help.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind,  this link worked for me: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524956/visual-studio-2008-sp1-crashes-when-clicking-the-calculations-tab-of-an-ssas-cube-in-design-view